npm only finds module after "cache clean"
I have 2 different projects on gitlab:

"engine" publishes an npm package to gitlab's package repository.
"app" has this package in its package.json file and uses it

Everything was working fine until I tried to change a tag from an existing version to another commit.
Now, every time I publish a new package in "engine", when I run "npm install" in the "app" project npm says it cannot find that version.
However, when I run npm cache clean --force, npm is able to find the package.
Is there any way to fix this? Is there something I can configure to stop having to clean the cache every time I need to update the version of the package?
